# Using javascript to create a checkbox with a label to the right

Tags: javascript, html, dom, checkbox, label

I'm using Javascript to construct a html, I'm trying to put a label to the right of the checkbox.

I tried different line order with the Javascript code and different appendChild order, but I never get the result I want.

```
    const div_recordar_login = document.createElement("div");
    div_recordar_login.classList.add("remember-forgot");
    form_login.appendChild(div_recordar_login);

    const label_chk_rec_log = document.createElement("label");
    div_recordar_login.appendChild(label_chk_rec_log);

    const input_chk_rec_log = document.createElement("input");
    input_chk_rec_log.type = "checkbox";
    label_chk_rec_log.textContent = "Recordar usuario ";
    label_chk_rec_log.appendChild(input_chk_rec_log);
```

This is what I expect in html

```
    <div class="remember-forgot">
    <label><input type="checkbox">Recordar usuario</label>
```

This is what I'm getting

```
    <div class="remember-forgot">
         <label>
         Recordar usuario 
         <input type="checkbox">
         </label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to append (not appendChild) a string to the checkbox input.

```
const input_chk_rec_log = document.createElement("input")
input_chk_rec_log.type = "checkbox"
label_chk_rec_log.appendChild(input_chk_rec_log)
label_chk_rec_log.append(" Recordar usuario")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const div_recordar_login = document.createElement("div");
div_recordar_login.classList.add("remember-forgot");

form_login.appendChild(div_recordar_login);

const label_chk_rec_log = document.createElement("label");
div_recordar_login.appendChild(label_chk_rec_log);

const input_chk_rec_log = document.createElement("input");
input_chk_rec_log.type = "checkbox";
label_chk_rec_log.appendChild(input_chk_rec_log);

// create a span element for the label text and append it after the checkbox input
const label_text_span = document.createElement("span");
label_text_span.textContent = "Recordar usuario";
label_chk_rec_log.appendChild(label_text_span);
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what they did wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: When I set the textContent after the appendChild(input_chk_rec_log) line, the <input type="checkbox"> line disappears from the generated HTML

Comment: try create a separate span element for the label text and append it after the checkbox input. 
if that works out, you can create a textNode also.


const label_text = document.createTextNode("Recordar usuario");
label_chk_rec_log.appendChild(label_text);

// append the checkbox input after the label text
label_chk_rec_log.appendChild(input_chk_rec_log);